# How did the T-Rex kill everyone on the boat?

Tags: plot-explanation, lost-world-jurassic-park

In *Jurassic Park: The Lost World*, a T-Rex is captured from the island, sedated, and put on a boat for the mainland.  During the trip to the mainland, the T-Rex got free and killed everyone.  When the boat arrives, our intrepid heroes find that in the ship's control room, there are body parts.  How did the T-Rex manage to kill people in that room?  All of the doors look smaller than the T-Rex's head, so how did she eat them?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I recently watched this and thought exactly the same thing. Looking into it a bit it seems the scene showing veloceraptors boarding the boat was scraped. Which makes sense - that whole last 30 minutes seemed out of place!

This from [The Lost World: Jurrasic Park's IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119567/trivia):

> The script called for a scene where the Velociraptors got on board the
>   Venture as it was about to set sail. As chaos ensued, the T-Rex also
>   got loose, and killed everything else aboard. This explains why many
>   of the crew members are dead in places the Rex cannot reach. The scene
>   was never filmed.

Answer (score 10):

I think this is a plot hole of the movie. We really don't know what happened aboard the ship, except that the T-Rex was tranqualized and then counteracted.
There were 2 T-Rexes, but as told to Ian Malcolm (Jeff Goldblum), the infant T-Rex was brought back on the plane. This person was obviously there for the loading of the T-Rex on the boat, witness to the injections, who then accompanied the baby on the plane. Only the adult T-Rex was on the ship, tried to escape through the cargo hold doors (they were ajar, maybe warped from the inside), then escaped when the doors were lifted by the guard after arrival.
All this would suggest that some human being locked the T-Rex in the cargo hold AFTER the slaughter, but who could do that, and with what bait? AND, if there was someone still alive, why drive the ship into the dock at full speed?

Answer (score 4):

[*T. rex* had strong forelimbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrannosaurus#Arms), and while they were likely evolved to deal with struggling prey larger than human, once the tyrannosaur got hungry enough "life found a way."  At least one person had to go up to the wheelhouse to control the ship, and the dinosaur presumably killed the crew one by one as they emerged from below decks.